# is the UI of 'VideoRecorder' component from 'react-video-recorder' customizable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to implement video recording in my react application and I found 'react-video-recorder' useful but I couldn't find a way to customize it's ugly UI.

is there a way to customize it ? or is there a better package I could use for the same function ?

Answer (score 0):

The 'react-video-recorder' component provides limited customization options. You can customize aspects like the mimeType, the time limit for recording, the countdown time, etc. However, for full control over the UI design, you'll likely need to build a custom video recorder component. For complex customization, it is better to use lower-level libraries that allow more control over the UI and functionality, such as 'MediaStream' or 'MediaRecorder' APIs.

We recently had to create an in house solution for a companies training videos and we used this url for a reference (not my site)  https://code.pieces.app/blog/react-player-customized-controls